# Schauder basis for C([0,1])

Tags: functional-analysis, schauder-basis

How can I prove that a system $\{t^k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ is not a Schauder basis for C([0,1])
I tried to come up with a function that on the one hand is equal to 1 when t->1, and on the other hand given series $\sum_0^{\infty}{\alpha_k t^k}$ doesn’t converge. And that will contradict a definition of a Schauder basis

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Is the upper limit, $\ -\infty\ $, in $\ \left\{t^k\right\}_{k=0}^{-\infty}\ $ a typo, or did you *really* mean to ask whether $\ \left\{t^{-k}\right\}_{k=0}^{\infty}\ $ is a Schauder basis?   The answer to that question would obviously be "no", because $\ t^{-k}\not\in C([0,1])\ $ for $\ k>0\ $.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo

Comment: @postmortes Fischer's explanation in that other thread is fine, but his explanation is _not_ just what you say here. The argument you give would contradict the fact that every continuous function _is_ the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

If $f \in C[0,1]$ then the following series uniformly converges: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\alpha_k}$.
Therefore:
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{k \alpha_k t^{k-1}}$ uniformly converges $\forall t \in (0,1)$. 
It implies that for any $f \in C[0,1]$  $f \in C^1{[0,1]}$. And it’s clearly not true